Unable to start Docker
I am unable to start Docker Desktop. When ever I open the app it gets stuck on 'Starting the Docker Engine' and then gives the following error:
provisioning docker WSL distros: ensuring main distro is deployed: deploying "docker-desktop": importing WSL distro "Failed to configure network (networkingMode Nat). To disable networking, set `wsl2.networkingMode=None` in C:\\Users\\hp\\.wslconfig\r\nError code: Wsl/Service/RegisterDistro/CreateVm/ConfigureNetworking/HNS/ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND\r\n" output="docker-desktop": exit code: 4294967295: running WSL command wsl.exe C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe --import docker-desktop <HOME>\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\distro C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\wsl\wsl-bootstrap.tar --version 2: Failed to configure network (networkingMode Nat). To disable networking, set `wsl2.networkingMode=None` in <HOME>\.wslconfig
Error code: Wsl/Service/RegisterDistro/CreateVm/ConfigureNetworking/HNS/ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
: exit status 0xffffffff
checking if isocache exists: CreateFile \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\isocache\: The network name cannot be found.

I have tried every method but the app is not starting. Also there is no .wslconfig file in the location.
Any solution to this?

I think this is better suited in superuser but a quick google search also revealed https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10709 and https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10666 .

Do you have wsl and its distribution environment in place?
I suggest you check the Docker prerequisites.
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/wsl/#prerequisites
I referred you to Docker Failed to Start.

yes i have wsl. docker was working fine till last night, i deleted some containers that were running in it and when i opened it again it started to give error

hummmm... This may be a similar issue to https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/11334. It might be a good idea to use the https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/11334#issuecomment-2013628616 method to get the logs and write down the details or listen to them in https://github.com/microsoft/WSL. I am sorry that I can not be a help.
